# Print a two-dimensional array into a table in AngularJS

Tags: html, arrays, angularjs, html-table, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a two-dimensional array received from controller which I can access in html like this: `$ctrl.myTable`.

All sub-arrays have the same length but there can a changeable number of sub-arrays.

It has this form:

```
$ctrl.myTable = [[111, 222, 333, 444, ...],
                 [123, 234, 345, 456, ...],
                 ...
                ];
```

I want to put it into a table. I managed to put the table header (which is an one-dimensional array with same length as the sub-arrays of the first one) but I don't know how to put each value on a separate row.

```
<div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.tableTitle">{{label}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.tableTitle">{{$ctrl.myTable[0]}}</td></tr>                        
                </tbody>
            </table>

</div>
```

Like this I only have the first sub-array as the first element on a row.

My goal it to have it like this:

```
name1 name2 name3 name4 
111     123   ...  ...
222     234   ...  ...
333     345   ...  ...
444     456   ...  ...
...     ...   ...  ...
```

Do you have any idea how to go through the array to make it like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `tbody` code by:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="rows in $ctrl.myTable[0]">
        <td ng-repeat="label in $ctrl.tableTitle">{{$ctrl.myTable[$index][$parent.$index]}}</td>
    </tr>                        
</tbody>
```